# Viewset's list() and Filtering conflict

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

When I set a ViewSet with both filtering and `list()` function -> filtering stops work:

```
class ClientViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ClientSerializer
    queryset = Client.objects.all()
    filter_class = ClientFilter

    def list(self, request):
        serializer = ClientSerializer(self.queryset, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
```

Here is my filter class:

```
class ClientFilter(FilterSet):
    type = CharFilter(name='type', lookup_expr='iexact')
    parent_id = NumberFilter(name='parent__id')
    title = CharFilter(name='title', lookup_expr='icontains')

    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = {
            'type', 'parent_id', 'title'
        }
```

> Please note

that without a `list()` method filtering works perfectly, I checked that thousand times. I'm 100 % sure that `list()` is exactly what causing the issue, I just don't know why and what exactly to do to solve this conflict.

Comment: I would suggest use `get_queryset` instead of `filter_class`. `filter_class` useful in `generics.ListAPIView` only. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`filter_queryset`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#filter_querysetself-queryset) method:

```
def list(self, request):
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.queryset)
    serializer = ClientSerializer(queryset, many=True)
    return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
```

Comment: Thanks! There was no conflict after all, it was just me being inattentive